# Crashlytics - 0 crashes (iOS 12, Xcode 10 GM)

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, xcode10

We released our app (phased release) with support of iOS 12 that was built by Xcode 10 GM yesterday morning, and still can't see crashes in Crashlytics tab:

[image: Crashlytics pic]

However, we found amount of all crashes in Launch status for this version of the app:

[image: Launch status]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a “Missing dSYM” alert in Crashlytics, asking you to upload your dSYM files for that release.  Or go [here](https://fabric.io/settings/apps) and click on your app, then click on "Missing DSYMS" tab to see if you need to upload any.

Here's a Fabric/Crashlytics doc about it: [Missing dSyms](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html)

I recently added some missing dSYMs and then was flooded (in email) with several crash reports that had accumulated.  (I had always thought I'd get the email notices of crashes regardless of dSYMs, so I suspect they changed their behavior recently).

In fact, I just looked at your second screenshot where Crashlytics suggests you might have missing dSYMs.

Comment: We have missing dSYMs because we tried to check if it works at all: in dSYMs we have only fake ones that we made ourselves.

Comment: What's meant by "made ourselves"?  The app you shipped to AppStore was built with a local Xcode, right?  That local Xcode has the .dSYM files (see Organizer window to find the local directory they live in).  I don't know how you can fake a dSYM, or expect Crashlytics to work if you did manage to fake one.

Comment: Yes, with the local Xcode, sure. Thank you for the help, we'll try to add missing dSYMs :)

Comment: Finally, crashes are here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Woot!  Great to hear.  If you wouldn't mind marking my answer as the accepted answer, I'd appreciate it.  All the Best!

Comment: Same issue here with Xcode 9.4.1, but this solution does not help. In my case crashes are not listed in `missing dSYM` and I have already uploaded the proper `dSYM` several times.